# Unable to access codebehind variable in javascript in the aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to access a string from code behind into javascript in aspx page

code behind

```
  protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            List<string> imageList = new List<string>();
            string images="";
            imageList = GetMatchingImages(@"C:\Users\Shahzad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ImageSearchEngine\ImageSearchEngine\Images", txtSearch.Text);

            foreach (var image in imageList)
            {
                images += "\"" + image + "\",";
            }
            images ="["+ images.Substring(0, images.Length - 1)+"]";

        }

        public List<string> GetMatchingImages(string path, string keyword)
        {
            var matches = new List<string>();

            var images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);

            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                if (image.Contains(keyword))
                {
                    matches.Add(image);
                }
            }

            return matches;
        }
```

and in the aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var imagesList;
     function getImages()
     {
         return <%=images%>;
     }
     imagesList = getImages();
 </script>
```

but it is giving error 'images does not exist in the current context' plz help me find out where I am making the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be issue of the scope of images variable. Try declaring it outside btnSearch_Click function.

This could possibly fix the problem as images is currently inaccesible outside of this function.

Thanks, zryw141

Comment: Outside of the function and `protected` or `public` :-)

Comment: simba, if you can, mark the asnwers that helped you solve your problem as accepted answer. This will help other people that might have similar problem in the future and will help people focus on answers that haven't been answered yet.